# How can a bne branch work without a previous cmp compare in ARM sssembly?

Tags: assembly, arm

I'm learning subroutines in Arm assembly and I'm confused with an example. For "   bne Body " doesn't it need a cmp x, y before it? What's it comparing?

```
@ Sum of the first "MAX" Fibonacci with subroutine
.text
.global _start
.equ MAX,10
_start: mov r1,#MAX
bl Fib 
exit: swi 0x11 @ Terminate the program
@Subroutine to compute sum of n Fibonacci numbers
Fib: sub r1,r1,#2 @ Counter - 2
mov r2,#1
mov r3,#2
mov r0,#3
Body: add r4,r2,r3
add r0,r0,r4 @ Update Sum
mov r2,r3
mov r3,r4
Decr: subs r1,r1,#
bne Body @ If Count != 0, repeat loop
Done: mov pc,lr @ Return from subroutine
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 'subs' instruction sets flags, and the 'bne' is branching on those flags.  Basically, it's comparing r1 to 0 and branching if it's not equal to 0.  A compare is actually performed as a subtract operation - that's how you compare 2 numbers in a CPU.  Older CPUs didn't even have compare opcodes, and many that do are really just synonyms for subtract (there might be minor differences in flags set, and also for clarity you should use a compare opcode if one exists).

Comment: Ok thanks. Is there any other instructions that set the flags (e.g. add) that I should be aware of?

Comment: Yes, there are many of them.  Most instructions that do ALU operations (math or logic) can set flags under some conditions.  Instructions that simply move data around or branch the flow of the program usually do not.  To be sure, and to know what flags might be set under what conditions, you really need to see the docs for the instructions.

Comment: Note the second 's' in the "subs" instruction, it indicates that flags are set according to its result (e.g. the "sub" instruction doesn't set flags).

Comment: Worth mentioning that the key difference between CMP and SUB is that CMP only writes flags, not an integer register.  Do any assembly languages really use CMP as an alias for SUB when it's only available as a destructive operation?  I guess in a RISC machine with 3-operand instructions and an always-0 register, you could just use the zero-register as the destination.  (MIPS would be like that, but it doesn't use flags at all, and has CMP instructions that put a boolean result in the destination, IIRC.)